# Can I request only the month in a DBKnex Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, knex.js

I am working on a React + Knex + sqlite3 website. I want to receive informations that will later be used to generate a graph. This is the current route.

```
router.get("/data/graph",async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const totalPerMonth = await dbKnex("books")
        .select('sell_date')
        .sum({ total: "price" })
        .groupBy("sell_date");
        res.status(200).json(totalPerMonth);
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(400).json({msg:error.message});
    }
})
```

"price" is a float value, and "sell_date" is a date value.
The problem is that I'm not getting the month, and instead, I'm getting the entire date, with day, month and year. How do I fix that?

I do realize I need to specify the request, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use `.raw()` to create a month-year variable to group on. The specifics of the raw query may depend on the underlying database.

For postgres for example you can use the [to_date()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) function

```
const totalPerMonth = await dbKnex("books")
  .select(dbKnex.raw("to_date(sell_date,'YYYY/MM')"))
  .sum({ total: "price" })
  .groupByRaw("1");
```

This should group by '2023-01', '2023-02' etc…

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to fix it. The problem was that I didn't know the query depended on the database (sqlite3). After I figured that out, I was able to do the code as I wanted it to. <3